# Wicket Checkbox onUpdate not being called on JQuery changing check state

Tags: jquery, checkbox, wicket-6

I have a data table that I've added a panel into which holds a checkbox in a cell. I have another panel that has a checkbox which I use to select all the checkboxes in the data table. The Select All is done by JQuery and the JQuery is in the code below. How can I get the onclick or onchange event to be called when my JQuery Select All checkbox is checked? I've tried using the AjaxCheckBox below but the event is not being called.

```
    private static List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
    private static class ActionsPanel extends Panel {

    public ActionsPanel(String id, IModel<WorkOrderCustomer> model, final String uuid ) {
        super( id );

        AjaxCheckBox checkBox = new AjaxCheckBox("checkbox", Model.of(Boolean.FALSE)) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
                super.onComponentTag(tag);
                tag.append("class", uuid, " ");
            }

            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                if( getModelObject() == true ) {
                    checkBoxes.add(this);
                } else {
                    checkBoxes.remove(this);
                }
            }
        }; 
        add( checkBox );
    }
}
    private static class ActivityPanel extends Panel {

    private final String selectCheckboxJS = "if($(this).attr('checked') == 'checked') {var val=true;} else {var val=false;}$('." + 
                                uuid + "').each(function() { $(this).attr('checked', val); });"
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Inject
    private Dao dao;
    private DropDownChoice<String> activities;

    public ActivityPanel(String id, final String selectCheckboxJS, FilterForm form) {
        addActivitySwitchPanel(selectCheckboxJS, form);
    }

    private void addActivitySwitchPanel(final String selectCheckboxJS, FilterForm form) {

        CheckBox checkAll = new CheckBox("checkAll"); 
        checkAll.add(new ChangeActivitySearchBehavior() {
            @Override
            public void onComponentTag(Component component, ComponentTag tag) {
                tag.put("onclick", selectCheckboxJS);
            }
        });

        SubmitLink changeActivityLink = new SubmitLink("activityLink", form);
        add( checkAll );
        add( changeActivityLink );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just changing the value of `checked` attribute you could `$(this).trigger('click')` on the checkboxes.

Also take a look at `org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.CheckGroupSelector` component.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was so zeroed in on thinking I was going to have to solve this through wickets that I didn't even think of trying jQuery. I did look into GroupSelector when I was initially designing this but due to the way we've structured the class I didn't have a direct handle to those checkboxes without going through some funky redesign.